# Hibernate is adding unwanted column to table that is not mapped or defined

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I set up Spring-Boot to use Hibernate to load data from an embedded H2-database. The schema in this database will automatically be generated with the `schema.sql` script and then will be filled with data from the `data.sql` file.

The content of my `schema.sql` is:

```
CREATE TABLE BusinessModel (
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(1024),
IMAGEURL VARCHAR(128)
);
```

The problem is that hibernate automatically adds an additional column to the table that is not defined in the `schema.sql`. In the log of the application I can find this line:

```
Hibernate: alter table APP.PUBLIC.BUSINESSMODEL add column image_url varchar(255)
```

So a column `image_url` is automatically added. In the H2-Console I can see the table and its content. There all columns from `schema.sql` are added and filled with the correct data. Additionally the `image_url` column is added and remains empty. Inside my entity the `imageurl` column is mapped the following way:

```
@Column(name = "imageurl")
public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}
```

Now my problem is that Hibernate is referencing and loading data from `image_url`, which is not correct. Until now I couldn't find any file where `image_url` is defined. Is there some typ of cache that has to be cleared? I restarted the application multiple times, droped the table and changed the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` from `none` to `create-drop` back to `none`.

**UPDATE 1**
The complete BusinessModel class:

```
@Entity
```

@Table(name = "businessmodel")
public class BusinessModel implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3152463846487623463L;

@Id
private int id;

private String name, description, imageUrl;

public BusinessModel() {

}

@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getID() {
    return id;
}

public void setID(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "description")
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

@Column(name = "imageurl")
public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

}
```

I'm using Spring-Boot 2.1.2.REALESE and therefore the integrated Hibernate version. It seems to Hibernate Version 5.3

**UPDATE 2**
application.properties

```
# Hibernate
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show_sql=true
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

# Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:app;create=true

# Enabling H2 Console
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

Comment: Probably something to do with Hibernate Naming Strategies... https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy

Comment: `@Column` should override any naming strategy. Also `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` was set to `none`. That way hibernate shouldn't perform any DDL

Comment: Can you add whole BusinessModel class and database config?

Comment: What version of Hibernate are you using? It smells like bug to me.

Comment: It's documented. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy

Comment: @JB Nizet - `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is set to `none` - so it's not the case.

Comment: Did you tried set `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false`? Please add application.properties

Comment: @Tijkijiki using `false` will lead to an error in the EntityManger. I updated my post with the `application.properties`